# Creating a trigger to add new row to another table after new record using if statement

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mysql-error-1064

I cannot seem to get this trigger to work. I keep getting this error.

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to 
use near '' at line 6
```

```
SELECT * FROM website_queries;
CREATE DEFINER=`name`
    TRIGGER `add_subscribed_users` 
    AFTER INSERT ON `website_queries` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.subscribed = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO users SET id=DEFAULT, firstName = NEW.firstName, lastName = NEW.lastName, mobile=DEFAULT, email = NEW.email, admin=DEFAULT, createdAt = NEW.createdAt, subscribed = NEW.subscribed;
END IF;
END; //
```

I am using 10.5.15-MariaDB-cll-lve doing this through phpMyAdmin

Comment: You aren't setting delimiters. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-programs-defining.html

Comment: It's useful when posting if you include the table definition as text that way we can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Ahhh yes, will do next time, thanks mate below comment worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need in IF.

```sql
CREATE DEFINER=`name` TRIGGER `add_subscribed_users` 
AFTER INSERT ON `website_queries` 
FOR EACH ROW
    INSERT INTO users (firstName, lastName, email, createdAt, subscribed)
    SELECT NEW.firstName, NEW.lastName, NEW.email, NEW.createdAt, NEW.subscribed
    WHERE NEW.subscribed = 0;
```

In this single-statement form you do not need in BEGIN-END and DELIMITER too.

Comment: @P.Salmon True. I'll edit.. done.

Comment: Thanks for that mate, your correct. My first time using sql so using an if statement was my first thought.